# Paypal IPN callback not working since migrating website

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

We have migrated a bespoke php website to a new server on a new IP address. Since then the Paypal IPN system does not callback to the website so orders don't get updated etc. Could someone please give me some ideas of what to check on the webserver. Why would this stop working once the website has been moved to a new IP?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems to be working now. It must have been related to the domain IP change taking time to propogate through the internet.